# Unix shell scripting select and case statement

Tags: scripting, case, select

1) i want to write unix script which is like this

```
echo "Do u want to check application logs ???"
select opt in Yes No
    do
    case $opt in
    "Yes")
         commmands
     ;;
    "No")
    break
        ;;
    esac
    done

echo "Do u want to check non-application logs ???"
select opt in Yes No
    do
    case $opt in
    "Yes")
         commmands
     ;;
    "No")
    break
        ;;
    esac
    done
```

here after executing the first part its exiting and its asking the same thing again and again its not going to the other part i.e non-application logs

2)is this possible to use the two select and two case statements in the unix shell scripting if it is do please let me knoe the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

From the `bash` help on `select`:

> select: select NAME [in WORDS ... ;] do COMMANDS; done
>   ...
>   COMMANDS are executed after each selection until a break command is executed

The `break` command you do have in there is `break`ing the `case`, not the `select`. You need to put a `break` outside the `case` block.

For example:

```
echo "Do u want to check application logs ???"
select opt in Yes No
do
    case $opt in
    "Yes")
        commmands
        ;;
    esac
    break
done
```

Also, since this `case` only has a single action, you might as well use an `if`, but I'll leave that to you.